# Creation of multiple apache instances on a solaris machine

Tags: apache, solaris

I have a solaris machine. in that an application is running. in the same machine multiple developers are working with their own sand boxes(meaning each one have a separate code repository).

They are doing the code change in their own repositories. But to test that they have to copy all the files they changed to a place from where apache is running.

Now we want to change this environment such that every one should get a separate apache instances so that everyone have a separate url and they are more independent.

Please let us know the procedure to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the namevirtualhost directive, check out the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) on the subject.

Set each documentroot to an area readable by apache and writable by each dev to allow him/her to manage content.

Alternatively, look at using something like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) to provide each dev with an environment.